# Reordering output to predefined sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get output from a table sorted in a predefined sequence of 5 alphabet.
i.e.  L > C > E > O > A
by using order by I cant get the desired result. I am using SQL server db.

Can any one please suggest me if I can define a sequence inside a query ?
SO that I get my result in L > C > E > O > A.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What RBDMS are you using?

Comment: The poster is using Microsoft SQL Server, judging by the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when some_column = 'L' then 1
              when some_column = 'C' then 2
              when some_column = 'E' then 3
              when some_column = 'O' then 4
              when some_column = 'A' then 5
         end desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use those sorting criteria for two or more queries then you can create a table for this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomSort (
    Value VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    SortOrder INT NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.CustomSort (Value, SortOrder) VALUES ('L', 1);
INSERT INTO dbo.CustomSort (Value, SortOrder) VALUES ('C', 2);
INSERT INTO dbo.CustomSort (Value, SortOrder) VALUES ('E', 3);
INSERT INTO dbo.CustomSort (Value, SortOrder) VALUES ('O', 4);
INSERT INTO dbo.CustomSort (Value, SortOrder) VALUES ('A', 5);
GO
```

and then you can join the source table (`x` in this example) with `dbo.CustomSort` table thus:

```
SELECT  x.Col1
FROM    
(
    SELECT 'E' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'C' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O'
) x(Col1) INNER JOIN dbo.CustomSort cs ON x.Col1 = cs.Value 
ORDER BY cs.SortOrder
/*
Col1
----
C
E
O
*/
```

I you update the `dbo.CustomSort` table then all queries will use the new sorting criteria.